# Page with 50 internal page links or 5 pages with 10 internal links each?

Tags: seo, pagerank

I would like to know if no. of internal links in a page affects its page rank or not?

lets say:
a page contains 50 internal links is better than 5 pages interlinked with each other having 10 internal links each is better?

Comment: Instead of worrying about how many links on a page affects SEO, you should be thinking "how does it affect my users?"

Comment: I think it depends on the type of page, but aside from navigational links, you really ought not have that many links on a single page in most cases. On most pages, you'll find about 10 or so contextual links embedded in the content, and then 20-30 links for navigation. Personally, I think that's a bit excessive, but it might be appropriate for larger sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, do not get caught up in the whole "I NEED EXCELLENT SEO SO I CAN BE SEEN!" thinking pattern.

I own a consulting company that specializes in SEO. Here are some things to consider regarding links:

Consistency:
The format of which the urls are written in must be consistent. For example, if you have a total of 100 pages, and the main pages are like this:
main-page1.html, main-page2.html, main-page3.html and some are like:
main_page.html, main-page.html, and mainpage.html, that is bad.

Keep the format simple, and consistent. either use a "-", or "_" to separate words and numbers in URL's.

Usability: What's the point of indexing a site if you can't use it?

Accessibility

Valuable Content: This is the most important rule. If your website has nothing valuable on it, why should it be indexed? And why should people visit it?

Now, to answer your question, what do you think would be easier for your VISITORS? Do you think it will be easier for your visitors to navigate around 5 different pages, or one page with 50 links?

One page with 50 links:
PROS:
They're all accessible from the one page, and can be easily found if you know what you're looking for, and if the site is well-designed.

CONS:
50 is quite a big number, especially when we're talking links.

5 Pages with 10 links:
PROS:
There won't be any pages that's jam-packed full of links. And it may be easier to navigate around 5 pages, than simply displaying all 50 links on a single page.

CONS:
If these links are not all related to each other, it can lower your pages relevancy. It could also prove to be very annoying if you have to click through to various pages just to find the one you want.

Conclusion:
Have you thought about a multi-level drop-down navigation menu just for these links, devided into categories and sub-categories, if applicable? That way, it can all be on the one page, and still be easy to find.

Answer (score 0):

I know SEO is a very important subject from business point of view, but usability, accessibility and design also does matter, and a lot, hence this other measures and features regards how your customers/users interact with your site. Do not forget about this.

Now from SEO point of view, having more than 100 links in one unique page, unless it is a detailed table of contents, starts to be bad.

Something around 40-75 links per page is the "normal" and "acceptable" from SEO perspective. (check SEOmoz beginners guide for further information).

Answer (score 0):

There used to be rules about not having more than 100 links per page, but that is no longer relevant - the average page on Wikipedia has over 300 links. So link whatever feels natural within the page content.

If the page is only a long list of links, I would suggest keeping that old limit in mind - for usability as much as anything else. More than 100 links in a list becomes unwieldy to parse and the user can suffer from the "paralysis of choice". Try and categorise too, if possible.

Comment: Wikipedia pages are an extreme case though. If you're writing something like a blog article, I think you'd be hard-pressed to find more than 20-30 contextually-relevant links that visitors might want to click on. On most sites that have large numbers of links, the majority of them is navigational, and only about 1% of them actually point to rich content.

Comment: I think the "link-to-text ratio" is the key here. Wikipedia pages have hundreds of links but it only accounts for a small percentage of the overall text.

Comment: Good point. I totally overlooked that. But in the case of very long articles, it may be best to paginate a little. In which case, if you have 1 link for every 50-100 words, and about 1600 words per page (about 3-4 "screens"), then you ought to only have about 16-32 links per page of content. And if you add another 20-40 links to that for navigation, then you should still be under 80 links per page.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Google Instant Preview now will do a big effort on checking site correct designs and how much of your links are on each page, affecting obviously your Instant Preview, so if you cannot make a correct 'fit' into theirs preview, your site will be punished